# How to make all the receiving! edge in Uppaal receive the channel? at once

Tags: uppaal

I have a system with 5 processes. One of the processes sends signal1! to 3 processes(That is the 3processes receive signal1?). But when I simulate only one of the 3 receiving processes received signal1. How do I make all the 3 receive this signal1 at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried declaring your channels of type "broadcast chan"?

Comment: Yes. still did not work.

Comment: Another issue, I don't know if this has anything to do with why all the receiving edges are not receiving signal.  The clock time in Uppaal, How do I read it.  I declare a clock x for instance, Can I see the way the time progresses.?

Comment: You need to rephrase your original question, it contains too many errors and misconceptions: model is one, maybe you have several processes? Sending synchronization has exclamation mark and receiving has question mark, meanwhile your text suggests the opposite. As for clock values, please read the Uppaal tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, obviously, the mixup in my question as regards sending! and receiving? is an oversight and as regards models in place of processes in uppaal. I was expecting anyone reading to understand, processes make up a system in uppaal while in many domains like mine models make up a system. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By declaring `broadcast chan channel1` each time channel1 will be sent, all the transitions in the other systems that can receive it will receive it at the same time.